# Given a width, height and angle of a rectangle, and an allowed final size, determine how large or small it must be to fit into the area

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

In other words, if I had a rectangle of $10\times 10$ and an angle of $45$, and the allowed area was $100\times 100$, the rectangle would be about $70\times 70$.

[image]

The allowed area is $100\times 100$ in red and the final rectangle is the blue $70\times 70$ rotated rect. I want to know how to get that "$70\times 70$" for any rect, angle, and area.

I believe the rectangle's original width and height are not important, only their ratio is.

Getting the above is easy if its a square, but I don't know how to do it if it is a non-square rectangle.

So what if I had a rectangle of $2\times 3$ or $200\times 300$ and an angle of $90$ degrees, that must fit into a space of $100\times 20$? Or some other arbitrary space?

Is there a general formula for determining the correct size of the original rectangle from the final area it takes up?

Comment: Yes, sorry. The rotation of the original rectangle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image: Rotated Rectangle]

We will be referring to the primitive picture above.  The original rectangle had horizontal side $a$ and vertical side $b$. It was rotated through an angle $\theta$ ($t$ in the picture).

We start with an $a \times b$ rectangle, with horizontal and vertical sides, such that the sides of length $a$ are horizontal. We rotate the rectangle counterclockwise about its center, through an angle $\theta\le \pi/2$.

How much horizontal and vertical space is occupied by the rotated rectangle?  (In general, the minimal containing rectangle will *not* be a square.)

The diagram above can be used to see that the *horizontal* space occupied is 
$$a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta,$$
and that the *vertical* space occupied is 
$$a\sin\theta+b\cos\theta.$$

For suppose that the side labelled $a$ has length $a$, and the side labelled $b$ has length $b$. Then the horizontal side $PR$ of the containing rectangle is made up of two parts. By basic trigonometry, the part $QR$ has length $a\cos\theta$, and the part $PQ$ has length $b\sin\theta$. Add up.  A similar argument deals with the vertical side of the containing rectangle.

If we want to fit the rotated rectangle into a *square* of side $s$, then the least $s$ that will work is given by
$$s=\max(a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta, a\sin\theta+b\cos\theta).$$

If we have a square of fixed side $d$ (in the post, $d=100$), we may want to *scale* the original rectangle to make the rotated version fit. Let $\lambda$ be the (common) scaling factor of the sides of the original $a\times b$ rectangle that will make the fit in the $d\times d$ square snug horizontally and/or vertically.  Then we need
$$\lambda \max(a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta, a\sin\theta+b\cos\theta)=d,$$
and now we can compute $\lambda$.

**Comment**: The same basic formulas can be used to solve some of the more general problems that you mentioned.  We obtained *separate* formulas for the horizontal and vertical space occupied by the rotated rectangle. Suppose that our target rectangle has given horizontal and vertical sides. We can compute the scaling factor $\lambda_h$ that will give a horizontal fit, and the scaling factor $\lambda_v$ that will give a vertical fit. Then the desired scaling factor for both a horizontal fit and a vertical fit is $\min(\lambda_h, \lambda_v)$.  (Here as usual we are working on the assumption that the *ratio* of the sides must be maintained, so a common scaling factor must be applied to each.)

Comment: "I really have to learn how to upload pictures" - sixth button from the right, on the toolbar above the box where you write your answers. :)

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed response. This makes it a lot more clear to me.

Comment: @J.M.: Thanks, I found the button. Usually I draw pictures in Inkscape, and use LaTeX to do the labels, exporting to .eps or (sometimes) .pdf.  What graphics extensions are supported?

Comment: I don't think EPS works for embedding here. [This](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/File-Export.html) says Inkscape can do PNG, so I'd use that.

Comment: Sometimes I scan hand made sketches and upload them as .jpg files.

Comment: @J.M.: My first diagram on this site! Now I need to learn how to make labels look right.  Have done it many times using a combination of Inkscape and LaTeX.

Comment: Andre, I have another related question if you are willing to tackle it: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61005/resizing-a-rectangle-to-always-fit-into-its-unrotated-space

Answer (score 1):

The important observation is that the width of a rotated rectangle is the greater projection of one of its diagonals on the horizontal axis.  If you have a $w \times h$ rectangle, its diagonals are $\sqrt{w^2+h^2}$ long inclined at $\pm \arctan \frac{h}{w}$  If you rotate the reactangle by $\theta$ clockwise, the angles become $\arctan \frac{h}{w}-\theta$ and $-\arctan \frac{h}{w}-\theta$ and  the overall width is the maximum of $\sqrt{w^2+h^2} \tan (\arctan \frac{h}{w}-\theta)$ and $\sqrt{w^2+h^2} \tan (-\arctan \frac{h}{w}-\theta)$.  The width scaling factor is just this divided by the desired width.  A similar computation can be done in height, giving the heights $\sqrt{w^2+h^2} \tan (+\arctan \frac{w}{h}-\theta)$ and $\sqrt{w^2+h^2} \tan (-\arctan \frac{w}{h}-\theta)$. and you just choose the minimum scaling factor to make sure it fits.